# How to use streaming chat GPT api response with voice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13

I'm using chat GPT API (createChatCompletion) where stream = true and I am also required to convert this streaming chat GPT API response into voice.

I am getting the streaming response in properly.

```
async function gpt(input) {
  const prompt = `The user has asked the following question: ${input} .Please respond to the user  in two to three sentences in very simple way.`;
  const response = await fetch("/api/chat", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      prompt,
    }),
  });
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(response.statusText);
  }
  const data = response.body;
  setIsListening(false);
  setGptloading(false);
  if (!data) {
    return;
  }
  const reader = data.getReader();
  const decoder = new TextDecoder("utf-8");
  let done = false;
  while (!done) {
    const { value, done: doneReading } = await reader.read();
    done = doneReading;
    const chunkValue = decoder.decode(value);
    setText((prev) => prev + chunkValue);
  }
  if (done == true) {
  }
}
```

Comment: See: [SpeechSynthesis API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis)

Comment: How can I use  streaming response in speechSythesis ?